# NameError: name 'di' is not defined in object

Tags: python, function, oop

I want to run di in **str** but it says NameError: name 'di' is not defined when I run it.

```
class DicePile:

    def __init__(self, initQuantity, initSides,initrollCount = 0, initrolled = False): # constructor
        self.setQuantity(initQuantity)
        self.setSides(initSides)
        self.__rollcount = initrollCount
        self.rolled = initrolled

    def __str__(self): # generate a string representation of the object
        rc = '(roll count:' + str(self.__rollcount) + ')'
        if self.rolled:
            resultString = str(self.__results)
        else:
            resultString = 'not rolled'

        return di(self) + ': ' + resultString + rc

    def di(self):

        return str(self.__quantity) + 'd' + str(self.__sides)
```

I'm still learning OOP and functions and this problem has been bugging me for hours

Comment: That's not how you call a method.. Use `self.di()` instead of `di(self)`

Comment: `DicePile.di(self)` would work, though that's not recommended, as it is both unidiomatic and bypasses inheritance.

Comment: What are `setQuatity` and `setSides`? I suspect they are trivial setters that can be discarded in favor of assigning directly to an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't pass self, you call your member function **on self**. Eg,

```
return self.di() + ': ' + resultString + rc
```

You might want to read the [Python tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Where you use the DicePile object, first create an object :
for example :

```
dice_pile = DicePile()
```

then when calling your method :

```
test = dice_pile.di()
```